# Javascript: window.setTimeout( ) not working

Tags: javascript, timer

I feel like this must be very simple, but for some reason I am getting no results from this:

```
<script>
function sendAlert() {
    alert('hello world');
}
var timer = window.setTimeout(sendAlert, 2000);
</script>
```

Should this not be counting 2000ms and then calling `sendAlert()`? Have I understood this wrong? I have also tried this outside of a variable (ie. `window.setTimeout()` not declared as `var timer`) and had no result either. This seems so easy, what am I doing wrong!?

---

UPDATE:

I'm an idiot. I had script tags with bad links to javascript documents in the header of my doc, breaking javascript in general on the page. Thanks internet. ;p

Comment: It works just fine. Did you wait 2 seconds?

Comment: If this works just fine than my copies of Chrome, Safari and Firefox are all broken! :P I also tried it as without `window.` and had no result either. : /

Comment: Your code is working fine [here](http://jsbin.com/esibof).

Comment: You could try adding an alert outside of the function, just to make sure the browser is getting to your code at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP just updated his post:

> I'm an idiot. I had script tags with bad links to javascript documents in the header of my doc, breaking javascript in general on the page. Thanks internet. ;p

Well, that explains it. Always check your error console! :)

Comment: Hilarious. As of today I earned the notable question badge for this. /facepalm

Comment: Consider that proof you’re not an idiot after all :)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is correct. However, the  tag might give problems. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendAlert() {
    alert('hello world');
}
var timer = window.setTimeout(sendAlert, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: it's not the problem because all major JS-supporting browsers since the dawn of time have allowed you to omit the `type` attribute.  In fact, some people recommend it, because `text/javascript` is an obsolete mime type for JavaScript.

Comment: @Before The `type` attribute defaults to `text/javascript`, so it can safely be omitted in this case. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-levels#level-1.

Comment: @MathiasBynens - Note that that's only the case for HTML5. Older specs require the `type` attribute to be present (whether implementations require that is another matter, but the spec says it must be there).

Comment: @JamesAllardice Why wouldn’t you use HTML5?

Comment: @MathiasBynens - I would (and I do). But the code in the question doesn't show a doctype so just pointing it out in case!

Comment: @JamesAllardice: the point was that it can be safely omitted in major browsers, regardless of doctype (thus suggesting this answer is incorrect).  The only difference is that HTML5 allows it to validate.